# Approximately how much for housing and food in Seoul, Korea?

Tags: budget, south-korea, seoul

I've been trying to fill out an application that requires me to list how much I think I will need for a 1-semester stay (about 3~4 months) in Seoul.

They require two separate fields for "housing" and "food".

For housing, I was wondering what would be an approximate average cost of a student apartment would be per month, and for food I was wondering how much would be needed as well (3 meals a day, with modest to moderate prices).

Comment: Seoul is an enormous city, and rents will vary depending on location. Which neighborhoods would you frequent for your research, classes, etc.? What is your tolerance for commuting time vs. cost?

Answer (score 5):

1) Food prices as of 2012, near colleage in Seoul:

- Cafeteria in a college : 2,000 ~ 4,000 KRW 
  (run by city/government has lower price)
- Local food resturant for student near a college : 4,000 ~ 6,000 KRW
- Franchise restaurant : 5,000 ~ 10,000 KRW

(near college in rural area will be lower about 500 ~ 1,000 KRW)

2) Housing prices : very differentiated by district.

- Gosiwon / Gosi-tel / Oneroom-tel / Living-tel 
  (just 1 room (about 3~5㎡) with private / shared(1 for 3) bath)
  : 300,000 ~ 500,000 KRW (up to conditions and options) with some deposit (key money)
- Hasook (lent a room of house. 4~5 people live in one house. Very different point of Hasook is it serves 2 meals (breakfast and dinner) : 200,000 ~ 400,000 KRW

Answer (score 4):

Although Korea is not an expensive country, Seoul is an expensive city. The cost of living in Seoul significantly varies from place to place. You cannot get an estimate without choosing your neighborhood. The cost for housing is more serious than cost for foods.